# how to see complete log on nitrous.Io console

Tags: meteor, nitrousio

i can't visualize the whole log in nitrous.io console , i'm using Meteor , and it's important to me to be able to see the complete log .

any suggestions ?

Comment: how you make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what type of stack your container is set up for, you should be able to use the Ctrl and +/- buttons to scroll through the console.

Otherwise  you can always use the less command by typing
*command* | less ([source](http://www.networkredux.com/answers/linux-in-general/working-with-files/how-do-i-use-the-less-command-in-linux))